# GPS distance: From point A to B ... and back to A

Tags: web-applications, gps, distance

I'm trying to add GPS to measure distance with my webapp.

I'm wondering if GPS works for this example...

Let's say I'm on a bike path.  I ride 30 minutes in one direction, then turn around and ride back to my starting point for a total timed ride of 60 minutes.

How can GPS measure the total distance?  My start and stop points are basically the same.

Or would I somehow have to measure two trips? (Point A - B , Point B - A)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured out the answer.

In the HTML5 Geolocation API there is a function call "watchPosition".
This function is called whenever the user moves to the next GPS point.

A distance calculation ([found here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)) will calculate the distance between the LAST point and the CURRENT point.

The distance method is called each time "watchPosition" is called to add the distance to a total.

I hope this helps someone.